# Move html elements from container to container

Tags: jquery, detach

I've to divide a text into portions. Text contains only paragraphs ( p tags ) inside `<div id="main">`. I wanted to insert some divs with id page1...pagen, and distribute the paragraphs  inside them.

Here is my code, but it is not working properly. Divs are generated before the paragraphs, and the paragraphs aren`t moved inside them.

Except the error, is there any more efficient way to do this?

```
    var n = 1;
    $('article').prepend('<div id="pagecnt">&nbsp</div><br/>');

    $('#pagecnt').append('<a href="#'+n+'">'+n+'</a>').after('<div id="page'+n+'" style="display:block;"></div>');

    var pargraph = $('p');
    for (var i = 0; i < pargraph.length; i++)
    {

        if ( $(document).height() < 2 * $(window).height() )
        {
            $('#page'+n).append(pargraph[i].detach());
        } else {
            $('#page'+n).after('<div id="page' + ++n + '" style="display:none;"></div>');
        }
    }
```

EDIT : this should be the result (basically)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's pagination you're after, but perhaps using the jQuery [Columnize or Columnizer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/columnize) plugin would work, then you could tweak to show/hide the columns created.

I had a play around with the idea, being a noob, it was a good exercise, I didn't use `detach()`, but `append()`.. then when the original "main" div was "empty" I 'swept it out' and and detached it  - In one of my original efforts there was sometimes children that didn't move out of the main div, I think it was the extra page** that eventually fixed that, but I added the final sweep just in case.

There are some issues, like clicking the top link doesn't color both counters whereas clicking the bottom link does (it doesn't on the fiddle?), **I had to add an extra overflow div to allow for uneven splits (paragraphs or children's different sizes meant the height splits couldn't be exact) - this extra div has never not been necessary in my tests but YMMV

It degrades fine when JS turned off due to CSS'ing the main div (`.article`)  the same as the pages

I still don't understand why the actual split splits into the columns rather than putting them all in the first page (not complaining ;)) - why/how does the loop know to put it into the 3/4 page divs?

#### My Effort: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/Q8kD4/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the links, but for the divs, if you want to put every paragraph in its own div, you can use [**`.wrap()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('p').wrap(function(i) {
    return '<div id="page'+i+'" style="display:block;" />'
});
```

If you'd post the before and after structure of the HTML, we could help more.

Comment: wrap can be used in single element, isn`t it? My intention is to group several p inside a div.

Comment: @Bakudan: I see. As I said, an example would be helpful. How are they distributed, do you hace a certain pattern (like equally distribution)?

Comment: @Felix Kling there is no pattern. The paragraphs contain random text. The script should move paragraphs until the height of the html is bigger than 2 scrols ( 2*$(window).height() ).

Comment: @Bakudan: Ah, I was wondering how this should work, but now I see that you set `display: none`. I assume the logic is a bit off here.  You say you want to put the paragraphs in the divs, but there must be some rule how to put them. It seems you keep generating divs and then put the remaining paragraphs in the last generated div. As I said, a before/after example and a demo would be nice. Makes it easier to play around.

Comment: I`ve added a pic, that represents my idea. @Felix Kling Just placing "p" inside the div pointless. "display:none" is important - it doesn`t take space and swaping the divs, shouldn`t change the page height much.

Comment: @Bakudan: Am I right that you basically want to put every `p` that is in the current view in a `div`. Then hide the `div` and put the next visible `p`s in it and so on. To somehow paginate the page...

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's what you're looking for:

```
 var n = 1;
    $('article').prepend('<div id="pagecnt"></div><br/>');

    $('#pagecnt').append('<a href="#'+n+'">'+n+'</a>').after('<div id="page'+ 
       n + '" style="display:block;"></div>');

    $('p').each(function(i){
      if ( $(document).height() < 2 * $(window).height() ){
        $('#page'+n).append('<p>' + $(this).html().remove() + '</p>');
      }else{
        $('#page'+n).after('<div id="page' + (++n) + 
         '" style="display:none;"></div>');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It will not work. `$(this).html().remove()` will give you an error. And this line is unnecessary complicated anyway and will remove and event handler that exists.

Comment: Alternatively you can do like this: `var pHTML = $(this).html(); $(this).remove();$('#page'+n).append('<p>' + pHTML + '</p>');`

Comment: Or just `$('#page'+n).append(this)`... as I said, no need to make it complicated.

Comment: :) absolutely. But the guy wants to remove the original paragraph or at least detach it.

Comment: So? If you append a DOM element to another one, it is removed from it's original location.